# jQuery Datatables Cannot read property 'length' with option bProcessing=true

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, datatables

This works fine:

```
<table id="dataTable">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>
           Title
        </th>
        <th>
            Creator
        </th>
        <th>
           Subjects
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
        </thead>

</table>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#dataTable').dataTable({
            "sDom": 'ft<"bottom clear"ip><"clear">',    
            "bServerSide": true,
            "iDisplayLength": 10,
            //"bProcessing":true,
            "sAjaxSource": '@Url.Action("GetMessages","Performance")',
            "aoColumns": [
                       { "sName": "Title" },
                       { "sName": "Creator" },
                       { "sName": "Subject" }]
        });
    });
</script>
```

If I uncomment the line "bprocessing:true" a get this exception
    Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined jquery.dataTables.min.js:65

The code where the exception was throw doesn say to much for me

```
function E(a, b) {
                if (a.oFeatures.bProcessing)
                    for (var c = **a.aanFeatures.r**, d = 0, i = c.length; d < i; d++)
                        c[d].style.visibility = b ? "visible" : "hidden";
                h(a.oInstance).trigger("processing", [a, b])
            }
```

a.aanFeatures is exist, but a.aanFeatures.r is undefined. Action in the Performance controller doesn't even get called.

Anyone?

Comment: in the developer console, see if  `a.aanFeatures.r` exists

Comment: nope :(
http://snag.gy/mXXEc.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things stand out:

There is no `<tbody></tbody>` in the table - add it after the `</thead>`.

In the `<thead>` section you have four `<th>` cells; in the aoColumns section, only three.  How many columns is your Ajax call returning?  The number of columns returned should agree.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I removed the empty th element, and added tbody. None of them worked :(
btw: ajax call would rutern 3 cols, but as a said, it doesnt even get called.

Comment: I have a jsfiddle for it.  When I comment out the sDom tag, or replace it with this "sDom": '<"filter_buttons">frtip', it appears to work.  Could you try that?

Comment: sure. It solved me too. Actually. The latter 'r' in the sdom options =(http://datatables.net/usage/options) stand for 'processing', and i skipped this from my first list :)

Comment: Aha... that's why the a.aanFeatures.r wasn't defined.  Glad it's working now.